# Two doubts on expectation inequalities

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expected-value, jensen-inequality, triangle-inequality

Let's define a probability space $\left(\Omega\text{, }\mathcal{F}\text{, } \mathbb{P}\right)$. Suppose to have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on it.
**Two questions:**
1. Could I state that $\vert E\{X-Y\}\vert\le E\{\vert X-Y\vert\}$ by Jensen's inequality?
 If not, *which* is the result used to show the above result and *how* is it applied?;
2. Starting from the fact that $\vert\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert\vert\le\vert X-Y\vert$, could I end up with $\vert E\{\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert \}\vert \le E\{\vert X-Y \vert\}$ simply by taking expectations on both sides? 
 What I mean is the following: if I know that $||X|−|Y||\le|X−Y|$, by monotonicity property of expectation I think that one can get $E\{||X|−|Y||\}\le E\{|X−Y|\}$. And then, since on my book I have the result $|E{|X|−|Y|}|\le E{|X−Y|}$ I am convincing myself that $E\{||X|−|Y||\}=|E\{|X|−|Y|\}|\le E\{|X−Y|\}$, hence that there is some way to prove that $E\{||X|−|Y||\}=|E\{|X|−|Y|\}|$. 
 If so, *why does it hold that $ E\{\vert\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert\vert\} = \vert E\{\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert \}\vert $?*

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: I hope I have clarified it somehow in the comment to the answer of user Targon. It was just a wrong thought of mine

Comment: You should never clarify your questions in comments, but rather edit your original posts to be more precise.

Comment: I'm so sorry @kimchilover. You are perfectly right. I have just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can state that and it indeed can be deduced by Jensen's inequality. However, it is more broadly known as the 'triangle inequality for integrals/expectations' and can be shown directly by the face that a Lebesgue-integral is the limit of simple functions, the triangle inequality, and the continuity of the absolute value.
2. That does not follow by taking expectations but by 1. with $$\big \lvert E \big( \vert X \vert - \vert Y \vert \big) \big\rvert \le E\big( \lvert \vert X \vert - \vert Y \vert \rvert \big) \le E \big( \vert X - Y \vert \big) .$$
   Following kimchi lover in the comments, I also don't understand your last sentence. The equation you give there is wrong, though.

Comment: What I meant is the following: if I know that $\vert\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert\vert\le\vert X-Y\vert$, by monotonicity property of expectation I thought that one can get $E\{\vert\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert\vert\}\le E\{\vert X-Y \vert\}$.  And then, since on my book I have the result $\vert E\{\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert \}\vert\le E\{\vert X-Y \vert\} $ I was convincing myself that $ E\{\vert\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert\vert\} = \vert E\{\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert \}\vert\le E\{\vert X-Y \vert\} $, hence that there is some way to prove that **[continue]**

Comment: **[continue]** $E\{\vert\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert\vert\} = \vert E\{\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert \}\vert$. In summary, I was not realizing that, as you stated, in part 2. simply 1. is used to get the result. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: unfortunately you lack the $\ge$ direction. But you can convince yourself that this equality is wrong by the counterexample $X = 1_{[0,{1}/{2}]}$ and $Y = 1_{[{1}/{2},1]}$. There you have $\neq 0$.

Comment: Perfect, got it! Just one last fact. Your second inequality above, that is $$ E\big( \lvert \vert X \vert - \vert Y \vert \rvert \big) \le E \big( \vert X - Y \vert \big)$$ is instead obtained by simply taking expectations on both sides of $\vert\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert\vert\le\vert X-Y\vert$, isn’t it?

Comment: precisely. (this comment has to reach 15 chars)

Comment: Great, thank you again :)

Comment: sorry, now I understood what you meant in your question. you had that part right already :)

Comment: What do you mean? That there is some way to show $ E\{\vert\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert\vert\} = \vert E\{\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert \}\vert $. From your above counterexample, I was convincing myself it is not possible

Comment: yes sorry for the confusion. that is indeed not possible. I meant your justification with "taking expectations on both sides" which you already gave in your question and I said in my answer it doesn't follow with that. because I didn't quite understand what you meant. now I do and that part is what you got right already in your question.

Comment: Crystal-clear now! Thank you a lot :)))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple proof of the inequality in Q1. For any real numbers $x$ and $y$,
$$
-|x-y|\le x-y\le |x-y|.
$$
Thus, by the monotonicity and linearity of expectations,
$$
-\mathsf{E}|X-Y|\le \mathsf{E}[X-Y]\le \mathsf{E}|X-Y|.
$$

Comment: Yeah, great way to prove it. Thank you a lot